# Bash script only read the first line of the file

Tags: bash

I wrote a script to ssh to remote server to find the disk usage of a user. However, this script can only read the first line, it doesn't continue on the other lines of the file. Anything wrong with my script? Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="myfile.txt"
while read line; do
server=`echo $line|awk '{print $1}'`
cpid=`echo $line|awk '{print $2}'`
echo $server "---" $cpid "---" `ssh $server grep $cpid /var/cpanel/repquota.cache|awk '{print int($3/1000) "MB"}'`
done < $FILE
```

myfile.txt contents:

server1  user1
server2  user2
server3  user3

Comment: Does the ssh command work from the command line?
You can use ssh -o CommandTimeout=20 ... to timeout a failing connection

Comment: Yes, the ssh command part works. I can get the result of the first line.

Comment: The second column seems like a user name. Is this really the same as `$cpid` or is there a third column?

Comment: What about ssh to server2? That is likely the blocker.

Comment: @Olaf, yes, the second column is a cpanel username. If I manually enter the command for each line, there's no problem.
echo server1 "---" user1 "---" `ssh server1 grep user1 /var/cpanel/repquota.cache|awk '{print int($3/1000) "MB"}'`

Comment: I just wanted to be sure, that it's not the user needed for ssh login.

Comment: I use ssh key for all those servers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ssh` call is inheriting its standard input from the while loop, which redirects from your file. This causes the `ssh` command to consume the rest of the file. You'll need to use a different file descriptor to supply the `read` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="myfile.txt"
while read -u 3 server cpid; do
  printf "$server---$cpid---"
  ssh $server "grep $cpid /var/cpanel/repquota.cache | awk '{print int($3/1000) \"MB\"}'"
done 3< $FILE
```

An alternative is to explicitly redirect input to `ssh` from `/dev/null`, since you're not using it anyway.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="myfile.txt"
while read server cpid; do
  printf "$server---$cpid---"
  < /dev/null ssh $server "grep $cpid /var/cpanel/repquota.cache | awk '{print int($3/1000) \"MB\"}'"
done < $FILE
```

Comment: I added the "-u 3" part to my original script, it works now. Thank you.

Comment: Had the same problem and this one fixed it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can simplify your read loop to

```
while read server cpid; do
    echo $server "---" $cpid "---" `ssh ...`
done <$FILE
```

and save the parsing with awk. Another simplification is to save the call to grep and let awk do the search for `$cpid`

```
ssh $server "awk '/$cpid/ {print int(\$3/1000) \"MB\"}' /var/cpanel/repquota.cache"
```

To your problem, I guess the `ssh` call doesn't return, because it waits for a password or something, and so prevents the loop to continue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to simplify the script, but I got syntax error.

Comment: bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `awk /user1/ {print int($3/1000) "MB"} /var/cpanel/repquota.cache'